# Get/Show google search results in my app

Tags: search, rss

I am facing a problem while developing an app, where I need to display search engine results directly on my app page without directing to www.google.com.

[image: Search RSS feeds/websites]

This is how it looks, in the search box I'll enter the RSS feed site name, and now I want to get the google search result on my app page so that I can easily extract RSS feed website and perform the operation I was intended to do.

I am intending only to get RSS feeds from the site just by typing sitename.

Thank you!

Answer.

Almost working..,
Thank you @Chandan,@Suzi

Comment: If I understood your question well, AFAIK, that is not possible. Have you taken a look at [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)?

Comment: Okey.! Then can you suggest me something ?? I want to get the RSS site url just by searching its name, not by entering the url.

Comment: Is [this](http://goohackle.com/tools/google-parser/) similar to what you want? If so, you may contact them or get ideas from the comments they've made. (goohackle says it's easy D=) The site seems to be unstable, [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8YCd5PhX63gJ:goohackle.com/get-google-results-in-a-text-file/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)'s the cached.

Comment: Yeah..! That's what I exactly want. But I don't know how to get the code for that..!

Comment: Well, unfortunately they don't seem to provide their code itself. Try contacting them.

Comment: Yeah!! So what ... ? no solution ?? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under [2. A Better Approach](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/call-google-search-api-in-java-program/)

I didn't try it out practically and am not sure whether its deprecated by this time or not.

Comment: PS: You need to use Google Gson library(jar) file to use this module. Let me know if you face any problems while implementing this approach.